# Using Powershell and ADSI to set local passwords

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'm trying to automate setting a bunch of local user accounts' password on a Windows 2008 server.  I've tried a few things and this works if I don't use a variable for the username like this:

```
 $user = [adsi]"WinNT://$computer/SomeUserName"
```

My script block is below...  any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$accounts = Get-Content c:\userlist.txt
$computer = SomeComputerName
$password = "MyPassword"
Foreach($account in $accounts)
{
 $user = [adsi]"WinNT://$computer/$account"
 $user.SetPassword("$Password")
 $user.SetInfo()
}
```

The error I get when I use the $account variable for the user (from the text file list) is:

```
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetInfo": "The group name could not be found.
```

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your machine tries to resolve the `$account` value to a local group name.

You can specify that it is a [User object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746543(v=vs.85).aspx) you want, by following the account name with a comma and the string `user`:

```
$user = [adsi]"WinNT://$computer/$account,user"
```

Comment: Thank you - that did it!