# "The group name could not be found"

Tags: powershell, wmi, adsi

when i am trying to run `([adsi]"WinNT://$env:ComputerName/$Username").SetPassword($Password)`command i am getting below error.

> The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetPassword": "The group name could not be found."
>   At D:\Install\ScriptsP12\3.InstallSQL2016.ps1:9 char:1
>   + ([adsi]"WinNT://$env:ComputerName/$Username").SetPassword($Password...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

I even tried the answer from "[Using Powershell and ADSI to set local passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549493/using-powershell-and-adsi-to-set-local-passwords)" with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts module is available on your system, you can try following code instead.

```
$UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name $Username
$UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It worked fine when i ran it locally, but for some reason does not do anything when i try the same through remote script.